# WebUSB `USBTransferInResult`s seem to contain partial interrupt transfers

Tags: usb, webusb

I'm using the WebUSB API in Chrome. I can pair with the device, claim an interface, and begin listening to an inbound interrupt endpoint that transfers three bytes every time I press a button, and three more when the button is released (it's a vendor-specific MIDI implementation).

The `USBTransferInResult.data.buffer` contains all of the bytes it should, except they are not provided transfer-wise. The bytes are being transferred one byte at a time, unless I do something to generate a bunch of data at the same time, in which case, there may be as many as three or four bytes in the same `USBTransferInResult`.

Note: The maximum packet size for this endpoint is `8`. I've tried setting it to stuff like `1` and `256` with no effect.

If I concatenated all of the result buffers, I'd have the exact data I'm expecting, but surely the API should make each transfer (seemingly) atomic.

This could be the result of something funky that the vendor (Focusrite - it's a Novation product) does with their non-compliant MIDI implementation. I just assumed that the vendor would prefer to transfer each MIDI message as an atomic interrupt transfer (not three one-byte transfers in rapid succession), as it would simplify the driver and make it more robust. I cannot see the advantage of breaking these messages up.

Note: If I enable the experimental-usb-backend, my USB device stops appearing in the dialog (when `requestDevice` is invoked).

This is the code I'm testing it with:

```js
let DEVICE = undefined;

const connect = async function() {

    /* Initialize the device, assign it to the global variable,
    claim Interface 1, then invoke `listen`. */

    const filters = [{vendorId: 0x1235, productId: 0x0018}];

    DEVICE = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({filters});

    await DEVICE.open();
    await DEVICE.selectConfiguration(1);
    await DEVICE.claimInterface(1);

    listen();
};

const listen = async function() {

    /* Recursively, listen for each interrupt transfer from
    Endpoint 4, asking for upto 8 bytes each time, and then
    logging each transfer (as a regular array of numbers). */

    const result = await DEVICE.transferIn(4, 8);
    const data = new Uint8Array(result.data.buffer);

    console.log(Array.from(data));
    listen();
};

// Note: The are a few lines of UI code here that provide a
// button for invoking the `connect` function above, and
// another button that invokes the `close` method of
// the USB device.
```

Given this issue is not reproducible without the USB device, I don't want to report it as a bug, unless I'm sure that it is one. I was hoping somebody here could help me.

Have I misunderstood the way the WebUSB API works?

Is it reasonable to assume that the vendor may have intended to break MIDI messages into individual bytes?

Answer (score 1):

On reflection, the way this works may be intentional.

The USB MIDI spec is very complicated, as it seeks to accommodate complex MIDI setups, which can constitute entire networks in their own right. The device I'm hacking (the Novation Twitch DJ controller) has no MIDI connectivity, so it would have been much easier for the Novation engineers to just pass each MIDI message as USB interrupt transfers.

As for way it streams the MIDI bytes as soon as they're ready, I'm assuming this simplified the hardware, and is intended to be interpreted like bytecode. Each MIDI message begins with a status byte that indicates the number of data bytes that will follow it (analogous to an opcode, followed by some immediates).

Note: Status bytes also have a leading `1`, while data bytes have a leading `0`, so they are easy to tell apart (and SysEx messages use specific start and end bytes).

In the end, it was simple enough to use the status bytes to indicate when to instantiate a new message, and what type it should be. I then implemented a set of MIDI message classes (`NoteOn`, `Control`, `SysEx` etc) that each know when they have the right number of bytes (to simplify the logic for each individual message).

Comment: This is exactly the answer I would have posted. MIDI is a serial protocol and what is likely happening is that the USB chip has a small buffer for data received over the MIDI connection. Whenever an IN transfer request is received from the host it will respond with whatever is in the buffer (up to the 8 byte packet size) and so if you are polling the device much faster then the MIDI data transfer rate you'll get one byte at a time because that's all that's in the buffer. This is how most generic USB to RS-232 serial converter chips work as well.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I vaguely suspected something like that, but it's useful to have it explained by somebody familiar with how these devices tend to operate. Thanks.